# How to get dynamic fields values - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, forms, dynamic-forms

I am quite new with jQuery and I don't know how to implement this scenario.

For example if I have a form with two text boxes in a raw Name and Email. At the right is a plus button where user can press and another raw will be created bellow with two fields Name and Email, the second raw will have at the right an X button that user can click and that raw will be deleted.

Name: ***_*__*_*_**    Email: ***_*__*_*__*_***    +

Name: ***_*__*_*_**    Email: ***_*__*_*__*_***    X

Name: ***_*__*_*_**    Email: ***_*__*_*__*_***    X

Name: ***_*__*_*_**    Email: ***_*__*_*__*_***    X

---

- SAVE -

At the bottom of the form there is a Save button. And when user press it the values from all boxes are take and saved ... that is not a problem.

My problem is how should I implement the dynamic fields and pick the values from the fields when I press save?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MKwHh/1/) 
  Try this code:

```
   $(document).on("click",".add",function(){
       //take the id
       var id = parseInt($(this).attr('id').substr(4));
       id = id+1;
       //add new row I don't know if you have a table or div layout

       $(this).after('<p><input type="text name="name_'+id+'" id="name_'+id+'"/> <input type="text" name="email_'+id+'" id="email_'+id+'"/><input type="button" id="remove_'+id+'" class="remove" value="X"/><input type="button" class="add" id="add_'+id+'" value="+" /></p>');
    });
    $(document).on("click",".remove",function(){
       //take the id
       var id = $(this).attr('id').substr(7);
       //delete
       $("#name_"+id).remove();
       $("#email_"+id).remove();
       $("#add_"+id).remove();
       $("#remove_"+id).remove();
    });
```

your html

```
  <p><input type="text name="name_1" id="name_1"/> <input type="text" name="email_1" id="email_1"/><input type="button" id="add_1" value="+" /></p>
```

Comment: Excellent!!! What about when you pick up the values on Save button? I sow you have a pattern with name_id, email_id. If I have 7 rows and will have the name_1 email_1, name_2 email_2, name_3 email_3 ... name_7 email_7 and user will delete the name_5 email_5 so there will be a gap ... I will guess I should use an array where I store the id's when are created, and remove the id when is deleted than iterate the array and get the values based on the id's in the array ... right?

Comment: Usually I use ajax and a file php with a foreach with the increment id  and after I save it

Answer (score 1):

If `save` means send data to server, you can serialize the whole form with jQuery `serialize()`

Example AJAX submit:

```
$(function(){
    $('#myForm').submit(function(){
       $.post('/path/to/server/', $(this).serialize(), function(response){
          /*do something with response if needed*/
       });
       /* prevent browser default submit*/
       return false;
    });
});
```

API reference: http://api.jquery.com/serialize

If `save` means store locally can use `serializeArray()`  http://api.jquery.com/serializearray/

Comment: So in this case no matter how many rows are in the form they will be serialized ? I mean in the case we have a gap in the id list 1,2,3,4,6,7 ... ?

Comment: correct... as long as field has a name which it has to have to submit to server anyway